# Opencart : How to add extra filter in admin product grid

Tags: filter, grid, opencart, admin, opencart2.x

I want to add a custom dropdown type filter in admin product grid. My `Opencart` version is **2.1.0.1**. can any one guide me to do this or provide any tutorial for this?

Comment: Open admin panel products grid> Inspect over Status dropdown filter > Copy any id of any element like I did `input-status` and search it admin core files using netbeans and follow the code for status

Comment: @Nimish can you explain it more ?

Comment: http://nimb.ws/tV9cdZ

Comment: When you will find the file follow the same code procedure and make another filter.

Comment: Thank u @Nimish , I have done it. Is it fine to make changes directly in core files or there is any other way to do it?

Comment: If you are confident that your code will be perfectly fine then edit core files. Another way to do which I know is using vqMod but as you are changing admin files so it doesn't matter